# Regular expression validate CSV

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regular-language

I want to check if a CSV file is valid using Regex but I have a problem.

Here is the example I want to match :

> [start]13 numbers;anything not containing ";"[nothing after this]

For example :
 
**match** :

```
1234567891234;some text
```

**doesn't match** because of the second **";"** :

```
1234567891234;some text;
```

The problem is when there is something after the second **";"**.

This one will match but I don't know how to avoid it:

```
1234567891234;some text; sometext
```

Here is the regex I use and an [example](https://regex101.com/r/fwxZyL/1/) :

```
^(\d{13});(.*(?<!\;)$)
```

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you tried `[^;]*` but since this negated character class matches line breaks, it did not work for you. All you need is to add LF / CR into the class:

```
^(\d{13});([^;\r\n]*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x7BKZp/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{13})` - Group 1: thirteen digits
- `;` - a semi-colon
- `([^;\r\n]*)`  - Group 2: zero  or more chars other than CR,  LF and `;`
- `$` - end of string.